# Is a larger css file slowing down Dom processing?

Tags: css, performance

Using a large `CSS` file, does it also slow down `DOM` processing?

Or the loading speed of the page is only affected by the file size?

I imagine that the browser when first loading the css file does

some kind on indexing to be able to use the css rules.

The parsing of the file logically will take longer for a larger file.

But the processing of the dom elements will be affected or not?

Comment: number of rules, and complexity of rules, might affect. size may affect if you have slow connection on server or client.

Comment: Stylesheet size does definitely influence loading speed of the page, that is why we have to minify css files (in production). Try to use preprocessors such as sass(with compass) to create as less files as possible (Number of file requests also slows down page loading speed).

Answer (score 1):

Not Necessarily!

According to [This link](http://sixrevisions.com/css/12-common-css-mistakes-web-developers-make/) and [This Link](https://benfrain.com/css-performance-revisited-selectors-bloat-expensive-styles/), there are many, many factors that can go into this Such as;

- Don't use @import
- Always use Backup Fonts
- Segregate large CSS files out into multiple Smaller ones
- Minify as much as possible

I hope this is useful to you :)